# Communication between leaf nodes

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, builder

I have a 'formbuilder' which essentially produces an hierarchical structure. I can do something like:

```php
$form = new FormBuilder();

$form->addField(InputField::class, 'title');
$form->addField(FieldSet::class, 'settings')
   ->addField(InputField::class, 'foo')
   ->addField(InputField::class, 'bar')
   ->addField(FieldSet::class, 'deeper')
      ->addField(InputField::class, 'deepervalue')
      ->addField(....etc....);

$form->setData([
   'title' => 'sometitle',
   'settings.foo' => 'foovalue',
   'settings.deeper.deepervalue' => 123
]);
```

Now - I can also have 'dependencies' such that when a field value is changed, I can invoke a callback:

```php
$form->addField(InputField::class, 'foo');
$form->getField('foo')->addDependency('anotherfield', function () {
   // code to manipulate the structure/values, here when 'anotherfield' is changed
});

// this will trigger the above.
$form->setValue('anotherfield', 'some value');
```

My question - is there a tried-and-tested approach/pattern for communication between leaf nodes at the time of change? Currently, my approach is quite primitive - I'm constructing the form, setting the data, then looping through each field applying the callbacks. Problem is - these callbacks can then add other fields which might have dependencies of their own that need triggering, so it gets a bit clunky and can be unreliable.

In my head, it feels like the best approach is to set up some kind of communication between dependent and dependency fields to immediately get informed of a value change. But then I find that I'm having to pass the top-level 'builder' down to all of the elements so that it can fetch the field it wants to communicate with, and it starts to get messy.

I'm using Symfony 5.4 at the moment (relatively inexperienced with it). I have played a bit with the EventDispatcher but adding event listeners to my Abstract form element classes causes all sorts of headaches, so I'm not sure it's the right fit.

Would anyone have any pointers, approaches I could try or design pattern examples that are effective but equally simple enough to maintain going forward?

Comment: I'm confused. Is this some custom form stuff? I mean ... there is a [form](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/forms.html#creating-form-classes) component that does all kinds of stuff out of the box and has a built-in event-system. I guess what I'm asking is: what has this got to do with symfony? They essentially have already recognized there are different levels a form can have, and writing logic for each level is easier to manage. You never want communication between leafs, usually. There must be an ancestor that's able to manage that. top down. for settings this should be enough

Comment: @Jakumi Thanks for the reply! Perhaps not related directly Symfony per se, but that's the toolset/infrastructure I'm using for the builder itself. The form component wasn't suitable for a number of reasons: our form definition itself is configurable by end user/admin, which produces JSON for a VueJs app. And our need to dynamically alter the form & its values in response to certain user interaction via an API.

Comment: tbh, that sounds really awful. My condolences - and I'm out of ideas / of my depth.